# How to set default value for null in Select Option in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have an array of values, and i am looping the array to display in Select Option

```
     <Form.Item label="Status">
        <Select
          value={user.status}
          onChange={handleStatusChange}
        >
          {status.map((item, index) => (
            <Select.Option key={index} value={item.status}>
              {item.name}
            </Select.Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
```

I want to "None" to be displayed by default when nothing is selected or when the value of the mapped item is null.

In other words, i want none to be the selected option when `status` is `null` or `undefined`.
I am using antd

Answer (score 1):

To display an empty value, you will have to add [`displayEmpty`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/#Select-prop-displayEmpty) to the Select, combined with [`renderValue`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/#Select-prop-renderValue).

```
      <Form.Item label="Status">
        <Select
          value={user.status}
          onChange={handleStatusChange}
          displayEmpty
          renderValue={
            (value) => {
              return value || 'None'
            }
          }
        >
          {status.map((item, index) => (
            <Select.Option key={index} value={item.status}>
              {item.name}
            </Select.Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [antd docs](https://ant.design/components/select) I would do it as following:

```
<Select
  defaultValue={null}
  onChange={handleStatusChange}
  options={[
    { value: null, label: 'None' },
    ...status.map(item => ({value: item.status, label: item.name }))
  ]}
/>
```

But as you're using form so you'll need to set your form item value:

```
form.setFieldValue('mySelectField', user.status ?? null )
```